# How to simulate a crack in a PCB?

Tags: electrical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis, finite-element-method, ansys

I want to break this PCB with some know force of X newtons in the bottom left tip of the PCB. The problem is that in Static Dynamics I just get infinite deformation and in explicit dynamics I really don't know what to do.

Anyone knows how to do this? I want to see the part crack away from the board.

[image: my problem]

Comment: Can you share the simulation package you are using to do the same?

Comment: Sorry friend, I did with explicit dynamics in ansys. After this post.

Comment: The link is broken, can you please fix the link